# How are big websites dealing with changes in their layout and/or code?

Tags: html

Since few days I have been learning HTML and CSS and it goes pretty well, but the first, quite serious problem that I faced was about the website's structure - how are bigger projects (few "main" pages and multiple subpages) dealing with even small changes in their code/layout?

Every tutorial I watched or read was based on creating very small websites, which were made of `index.html` and a few pages, let's say `sub1.html, sub2.html, sub3.html`. The idea was to create a layout of the page in `index.html` with all hyperlinks we were going to use and then, after we were done with it - copy its content to files `sub1.html, sub2.html, sub3.html` and change their content to our needs. This seems to be pretty reasonable for that small website, because we do not have a lot of code and changes should not take lots of time then.

But what if we are creating a website which will contain e.g. 50 subpages? How should we deal with changes on every single page, if we want to change the order of items in menu or do anything else with the repeating content of the website?

Comment: Keep on learning! HTML and CSS are important first steps, but when it comes to managing larger projects, you will appreciate some scripting libraries or "frameworks" (serverside or local) that will take care of the aspects you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a templating system of some kind, which will assemble full pages from components.

For example, you might have an outer template which sets up the basics like the doctype declaration, some common script and CSS includes, etc.  From there, one layer in, you might have a common header/footer.  Another template inside that might set up a page like the home page with featured content.  A sibling to that template might be inner pages which have perhaps headings and regular content.

Sometimes these pages are assembled on-request.  Other times, they are assembled when you change your content, and static pages are pushed to your web server.

Comment: Could you tell me how should I do it in order to keep all my future websites more "professional" from the moment I create them? I'd appreciate any kind of tutorials, just to get a small grasp of it?

Comment: Find a framework you like and try it out.  There are hundreds of current frameworks out there, all with various pros and cons.  For example, I often use simple EJS with a Node.js script to create pages which then get uploaded to the web server (which in my case is usually an S3 bucket, with CloudFront in front of that).  But, there are a lot of other ways to do this.  PHP with a template engine like Smarty is still a popular option.  There are heavyweight frameworks as well, like Laravel.

Comment: I just found [that PHP template tutorial](https://medium.com/@stevesohcot/sample-basic-php-template-for-file-structure-with-example-code-47ff6d610191) and it is exactly what I was looking for, also I am planning to use Bootstrap 4 to make my website responsive. Thank you for your answer!